# Vim script comparisson between a string and a filename-modifier

Tags: vim, neovim

so a very basic question, how can I compare a string with a file-name modifier like %:p:h. I got stuck because the comparisson always returns false

```
function! WhenEnter()
    if expand("%:p:h") == fnameescape("C:\\tools\\neovim\\Neovim\\bin")
        execute 'NERDTree "C:\Users\<user>\Desktop"<CR>'
        execute ':NERDTreeToggle<CR>'
    else
        execute 'NERDTree "%:p:h"<CR>'
        execute ':NERDTreeToggle<CR>'
    endif
endfunction()
autocmd vimenter * :call WhenEnter()
```

I just want to begin NERDTree in my desktop by default if I just opened neovim with the executable "because if not it just directs to C:\tools\neovim\Neovim" and for especific files I just want it to be the current folder.
I have tried a LOT of things to make it work, expand,fnameespace etc but nothing seems to make that comparisson work

Answer (score 1):

```
function! WhenEnter()
    if expand("%:p:h") == "C:\\tools\\neovim\\Neovim\\bin"
        execute 'NERDTree C:\Users\virgi\Desktop'
        execute ':NERDTreeToggle'
    else
        execute ':NERDTree "%:p:h"'
        execute ':NERDTreeToggle'
    endif
endfunction()
```

that is actually how I managed it to work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the *file-name modifier*, but with using `fnameescape` - see `:help fnameescape` for cases where this function is needed. In your case,

```
    if expand("%:p:h") == "C:\\tools\\neovim\\Neovim\\bin"
```

is correct (provided that the file path head is indeed `C:\tools\neovim\Neovim\bin`).

If still the `if` branch isn't executed, insert an `echo expand("%:p:h")` to see why.

Comment: thank you very much. The problem was also in the command NERDTree, is the reason why I though it was not giving me a correct comparisson when I tried that way before